# Core data large quantity

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I have 25000 records which are retrieved from a web service every time the application starts.
During the initialization phase I want to save all these items into core data.
The time for this operation is about 20 minutes.
There is possible to save all the items into the core data more rapidly?
It is a good idea to save them into the sqlite database using sqlite tools and then to instantiate the core data?

Edit:

20 minutes for saving into the core data.

```
func storeDevices(_ dataStack: DATAStack,value: [JSON]) -> Bool
{
    dataStack.performInNewBackgroundContext { backgroundContext in
    let entityDevices = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Devices", in: backgroundContext)

    for item in value
    {
        if !item["event_id"].stringValue.isEmpty
        {
            let id = item["id"].stringValue
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "id", id)
            let typesFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Devices>(entityName: "Devices")
            typesFetchRequest.predicate = predicate
            do {
                let fetchedTypesResults = try backgroundContext.fetch(typesFetchRequest) as! [Devices]
                if (fetchedTypesResults.count > 0)
                {
                    let typeUpdate = fetchedTypesResults[0]
                    switch item["is_Deleted"].stringValue
                    {
                    case "true":
                        typeUpdate.setValue(true, forKey: "deletedStatus")
                    case "false":
                        typeUpdate.setValue(false, forKey: "deletedStatus")
                    default:
                        typeUpdate.setValue(false, forKey: "deletedStatus")
                    }

                    if let intVersion = Int(item["last_modified"].stringValue) {
                        typeUpdate.setValue(intVersion, forKey: "lastModified")
                    } else {
                        typeUpdate.setValue(NSNumber(value: 0 as Int32), forKey: "lastModified")
                    }

                    typeUpdate.setValue(NSNumber(value: 0 as Int32), forKey: "syncStatus")

                    typeUpdate.setValue(item["deviceUUID"].stringValue, forKey: "deviceUUID")
                    typeUpdate.setValue(item["deviceLocation"].stringValue, forKey: "deviceLocation")

                    let event_id = item["event_id"].stringValue
                    if !event_id.isEmpty
                    {

                        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "id", event_id)
                        let typesFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Events>(entityName: "Events")
                        typesFetchRequest.predicate = predicate

                        do {
                            let fetchedTypesResults = try backgroundContext.fetch(typesFetchRequest) as! [Events]
                            if (fetchedTypesResults.count > 0)
                            {
                                typeUpdate.setValue(fetchedTypesResults[0], forKey: "event")
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                continue
                            }
                        } catch {
                            let saveError = error as NSError
                            print("Failed to fetch events in Devices: \(saveError)")
                        }
                    }


                    continue
                }

            } catch {
                fatalError("Failed to fetch devices: \(error)")
            }

            let deviceNewElement = Devices(entity: entityDevices!, insertInto: backgroundContext)
            deviceNewElement.id = id
            switch item["is_Deleted"].stringValue
            {
            case "true":
                deviceNewElement.deletedStatus = true
            case "false":
                deviceNewElement.deletedStatus = false
            default:
                deviceNewElement.deletedStatus = false
            }

            if let intVersion = Int(item["last_modified"].stringValue) {
                deviceNewElement.lastModified = intVersion as NSNumber?
            } else {
                deviceNewElement.lastModified = NSNumber(value: 0 as Int32)
            }

            deviceNewElement.deviceUUID = item["deviceUUID"].stringValue
            deviceNewElement.deviceLocation = item["deviceLocation"].stringValue

            let event_id = item["event_id"].stringValue
            if !event_id.isEmpty
            {
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "id", event_id)
                let typesFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Events>(entityName: "Events")
                typesFetchRequest.predicate = predicate

                do {
                    let fetchedTypesResults = try backgroundContext.fetch(typesFetchRequest) as! [Events]
                    if (fetchedTypesResults.count > 0)
                    {
                        deviceNewElement.event = fetchedTypesResults[0]
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue
                    }
                } catch {
                    let saveError = error as NSError
                    print("Failed to fetch events in Devices: \(saveError)")
                }
            }

            deviceNewElement.syncStatus = NSNumber(value: 0 as Int32)
        }
    }   
        try! backgroundContext.save()
    }
    return true

}
```

Comment: Two points the operation takes 20 minutes, is that 20 minutes to retrieve and store the data, if so what part of the 20 minutes is taken up just retrieving the data. The second point is that I believe that core-data uses sqlite for its storage, so I don't see how initially using an sqlite database and then converting to core-data is going to save you any time. However storing as an sqlite db and then using that instead of core-data may give you an advantage

Comment: What do you mean here by "save them into the sqlite database?" What sqlite database? Core Data is implemented on top of sqlite in many cases, but you should not modify that database directly. It is not a public schema. Core Data is an persistent object graph. It is not a database (it does not have "rows" and "columns" even if it can be stored in something that does). If you want to use a database (like sqlite) that's fine, but don't try to use Core Data as though it were raw SQL. What information did the Core Data Instrument give you about where your time is being spent?

Comment: Yes it should be possible to do this more quickly. But you need to describe (or better, show) what your code is doing. It's impossible to help optimize code without seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to optimise how you use CoreData.

Process your data and figure out what ManagedObjects will need to be touched, pre-fetch these in bulk outside of the loop. Watch out for any relationships that might also need pre-fetching. You don't want faults continually firing.

Now go through and make all your changes. Save once at the end.

If memory pressures is to great break the data into chunks of a few thousand and process them as above. Use @autoreleasepool.

Answer (score 0):

YES it is better to use the `sqlite3` functions to do batch insert. Since in core data it is not possible to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't take 20 mins to save 25000 records, have you tried starting multiple threads and contexts and save them to coredata. Please share your sample code and we can help. Below is a sample meta code to take less time for saving to disk

```
loop and create threads for every 1000 records using dispatch_async etc
on each thread, call dispatch_enter, create a thread context taken from parent root context
loop the 1000 records of this thread and upsert (update or insert) them into the context
save the context and call dispatch_leave
Finally know that everything is saved in dispatch_notify
```